# Inputmask поле ввода телефонного номера

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputmask

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой при разработки маски для поля ввода телефонного номера. Собственно сама маска: `$(".asPhone").inputmask("+7(99[9)]99[9-]9[9-]99", { greedy: false, placeholder: " " });`.
Проблема состоит в том что при начале ввода закрывающаяся скобка показывается сразу, в отличии от тире, которые показываются только после введения стоящей перед ней цифры. Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи как скрыть скобку до тех пор пока пользователь не введет третью цифру кода города?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена путем замены маркера группы (по умолчанию и есть те самые скобки):

```
$(".asPhone").inputmask("+7(99[9)9]9[9-]9[9-]99", { greedy: false, placeholder: "", groupmarker: { start: "<", end: ">" } });
```